# Function that tests another function for all numbers 1 to 1000

Tags: python, testing, for-loop

I've created a function named `number(x)` that tests a number to see whether or not a number is perfect or not. Now my goal is to create a tester function that tests all numbers from 1 to 1000 and return numbers that are perfect. This is the code i have for the test function:

```
def unittest():

    for i in range(0,1000):
        perfect(i)
        if True:
            return i
```

It's not working, but i think i'm close. Any advice or help?

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant this, and notice the correct parameters for `range`, and how we use a list to accumulate all the results - otherwise, the function will return only *one* value!

```
def unittest():
    ans = []
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        if perfect(i):
            ans.append(i)
    return ans
```

Alternatively, and *not* recommended (it's redundant), you could test if the returned value was `True`:

```
def unittest():
    ans = []
    for i in range(1, 1001):
        if perfect(i) is True :
            ans.append(i)
    return ans
```

Yet another alternative would be to use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is more idiomatic and potentially faster than using an explicit loop:

```
def unittest():
    return [i for i in range(1, 1001) if perfect(i)]
```

Comment: This will only return the _first_ perfect number. He want to return _all_ perfect numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When you `return`, that's the end of your function. If you want to return *all* of the perfect numbers, you have to keep track of them and return them all at the end.

On top of that, your `if True:` means you'll return `0` whether it's perfect or not.

So, what you need to do is:

```
def unittest():
    results = []
    for i in range(1000):
        if perfect(i):
            results.append(i)
    return results
```

---

There actually *is* a way to solve this without building the list, by using `yield` instead of `return`. That's probably too advanced for you to learn right now, but I'll explain it anyway. First, here's the code:

```
def unittest():
    for i in range(1000):
        if perfect(i):
            yield i
```

See the tutorial section on [Iterators](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators), and the following two sections, for details. But basically, a `yield` is like a `return` that doesn't return. What your function actually returns is not a list, but a generator. If someone then iterates over that generator, it will go through your function until the first `yield`, then go through until the next `yield`, and so on until you're done. The tutorial explains this much better than a single paragraph ever could.